# Running open Drone Map - getting an error from perl script

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I am trying to run  Open Drone Map which I have cloned to an Ubuntu 15.04 server I have installed all the required libraries. After I execute the code:

```
perl ../OpenDroneMap/run.pl
```

from within the directory I have all the  photos in  I get this error:

```
: , or } expected while parsing object /hash at character offset 11081 (before " " Mantis i23" : 45.00\n...") at ../OpenDroneMap/run.pl line 36, <$fh> chunk1.
```

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need to see the perl code that executes.

http://pastebin.com/nCy12Ezu

Comment: We indeed need to see the code; if it's extremely long post it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Please post your code. We can not guess line 36 without seeing code.

Comment: Added pastebin link to original post

Comment: @kos it is indeed **extremely long**...

Comment: The error is in your `ccd_defs.json` file. It's a syntax error in the JSON structure. Take a look at that file, grep for _Mantis i23_ or use an editor that alows you to go to character 11081 directly. If you created that file, fix it. If it's auto-generated, it might have broken escaping. Fix that yourself if it's a one-time thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your version of OpenDroneMap, it looks like it has already been fixed.

https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap

Latest commit:

```
commit 6b4d8b8cfc106182031f6b5f78976aff42836c54
Author: Stephen Mather <stephen@smathermather.com>
Date:   Sat Jul 18 15:56:53 2015 -0400

    fix for missing comma

ccd_defs.json | 2 +-
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase last line (not "}") from ccd_defs.json file. There is a non correct ":" character in Mantis i23 definition line.